# Sharepoint 2010 farm restore "CREATE DATABASE Permission denied in 'master'

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, restore

I am attempting to restore a farm backup to a new SharePoint install.

The OSW timer service is running under farm account.
farm account has `db_accessadmin`, `db_datawriter` and `db_securityadmin` membership on the '`Master`' database, yet I keep getting these errors.

What else am i missing - any help appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Farm admin account should need these two permission in order to create a database on sql.

- DB_Creator
- SecurityAdmin

Also make sure farm admin is part of local admin on the SharePoint server.

Comment: Yes, at the instance level, farmadmin does have those permissions.

Comment: how you performing the restore? can you share more details about the error....one more thing to check if NETWORK SERVIE account have dbcreator role on sql.

Comment: Yes, network service also has dbcreator role.I am performing the restore via central admin.

Comment: underwhich account Central admin app pool is running? also give farm admin full control on SQL server, i.e Sysadmin....after that logout from server and relogin thent ry again.

Comment: appPool runs under farmadmin account also - not ideal i know but i am trying to best replicate the current production server set up

Comment: i know it is not ideal, just for this restore try it once done then remove the sysadmin permission.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23580/discussion-between-perplexed-and-waqas-sarwar-mcse).